# send recorded Audio via WebSocket JS for Watson Speech to Text

Tags: javascript, audio, websocket, speech-to-text, mediarecorder

I'm trying to get microphone input and send it via Websocket for Watson Speech to Text, However it's being too difficult to get done, Can anyone help me on this?

```
var wsURI = "URL here";
var ws = new WebSocket(wsURI);
ws.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
ws.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
ws.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
ws.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };


function enableMic(){
document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();

    const audioChunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);  
    });
document.getElementById("stopButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
mediaRecorder.stop();

});
 mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
   const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      ws.send(reader.result);
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioBlob);

      audio.play();
      console.log(audioBlob);
      console.log(reader.result);
```

But I couldn't send audioBlob as AudioBuffer, So I'd like to send it via websocket. in this  last console.log the result is null

Note: Another functions from Websockets is not here because I think it's not impacting to understand.

I Appreciate some help!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending it before the reader reads the value ?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
ws.send(reader.result); // ?
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioBlob);
```

Comment: This is still showing as Null: see logs below:        onMessage:{
   "state": "listening"
}  
Blob { size: 34375, type: "audio/wav" }  
null  
onClose:1000

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the Watson Javascript SDK for the Speech-To-Text service? it already has the functionality you need I believe: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk

this demo page is based on that sdk: https://speech-to-text-demo.ng.bluemix.net/

Comment: I didn't tried to use this SDK because it seems to be used with Node JS and I'm trying to do it with Node Red and Javascript. So I could solve the problem by changing the following row:                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/ogg' });, but It's displaying the JSON results only in Firefox, Not in Chrome.